# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'checked')

Tags: javascript

I try to get the value of Checkbox through the following function:

```
function sickness_selection() {
    var element = event.target.id;
    // console.log( event.target.checked);
    element = document.getElementById(element);
    if (element.checked === true) {
        element.parentElement.classList.add("asanism-selected-radio");
    } else {
        element.parentElement.classList.remove("asanism-selected-radio");
    }
}
```

the function works but receives the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'checked')
    at sickness_selection (js_cEGLc76e0OdunEJf9-WqG_aDsYoNtkkBvpRxiXeaSmg.js:1701:17)
    at HTMLDivElement.onclick (create:1:1)
```

because the value does not render in the HTML file while changing the input:

```
<div class="js-form-item js-form-type-checkbox checkbox form-check js-form-item-sickness7 form-item-sickness7">
            <label class="form-check-label">
            <input data-drupal-selector="edit-sickness7" type="checkbox" id="edit-sickness7--iViLtzwqW-A" name="sickness7" value="1" class="form-checkbox form-check-input" required="">
              &nbsp;<label for="edit-sickness7--iViLtzwqW-A" class="option">somthing</label>
          </label>
              </div>
```

is there any solutions for error?

Comment: How is sickness_selection being triggered?

Comment: @Nitheesh - That information is hidden away in the stack trace (would have been much better if it had been shown directly): It's a `click` handler on the `div` (well, on **a** `div`, I'm assuming it's that one).

Comment: By far, the best way to find out what's going wrong here (as in almost all other cases) is to use the debugger built into your IDE and/or browser. Put a breakpoint on the first line of the event handler and click the element. Then, step through the function, looking at the values of variables, etc. Using a debugger is **not** an advanced skill. More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/) and [here](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that `element` is `null`, because `getElementById` returned `null`. The only reason `getElementById` returns `null` is that no element with that `id` exists (see [this question's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)).

But just that isn't the root of the problem. You're using a click handler on a `div` element (from the error message), then using `event.target.id` to find the `input` element using `getElementById`. There are two problems there:

1. If `event.target.id` were the correct ID, you'd **already** have the element: `event.target`.
2. It's entirely possible to click somewhere in the `div` that isn't the `input` element. `event.target` is the element that was clicked (in your case, that might be the `div`, the `label`, or the `input` itself). I suspect that's what's happening, you're clicking an element (a `label`, for instance) that doesn't have an `id`, so you're passing `undefined` into `getElemntById`, so it's looking for `id="undefined"` and not finding it.

Instead, given the structure of your HTML, you should look for the `input` within the `div` using `querySelector`:

```
const div = event.currentTarget;
const checkbox = div.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]");
```

Also note that `if (element.checked === true)` is more idiomatically written as simply `if (element.checked)`.

So doing all of the above:

```
function sickness_selection() {
    const div = event.currentTarget;
    const checkbox = div.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]");
    // assert(checkbox !== null);
    const label = checkbox.parentElement;
    if (checkbox.checked) {
        label.classList.add("asanism-selected-radio");
    } else {
        label.classList.remove("asanism-selected-radio");
    }
}
```

If you don't need to support Internet Explorer, you could use the second argument to [`classList.toggle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle#browser_compatibility) instead:

```
function sickness_selection() {
    const div = event.currentTarget;
    const checkbox = div.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]");
    // assert(checkbox !== null);
    const label = checkbox.parentElement;
    label.classList.toggle("asanism-selected-radio", checkbox.checked);
}
```

---

The above assumes that the handler function is hooked on the `div` that's immediately around the checkbox (again, this is an asumption I'm making from the error message). But in a comment you've asked how to handle multiple checkboxes, which suggests to me it may be on a `div` deeper in the document that contains multiple copies of the structure you've shown.

If so, the code above won't work (it'll always find the first `input[type=checkbox]` in that outer `div`). Instead, starting from the `target`, find that **inner** `div` to start with (see the `***` line):

```
function sickness_selection() {
    const div = event.target.closest("div"); // ***
    const checkbox = div.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]");
    // assert(checkbox !== null);
    const label = checkbox.parentElement;
    label.classList.toggle("asanism-selected-radio", checkbox.checked);
}
```

Internet Explorer doesn't have that `closest` method. You can probably find a polyfill for it. Or just replace it with a loop:

```
// If you really need IE support
function sickness_selection() {
    let div = event.target;
    while (div && !div.matches("div")) {
        div = div.parentElement;
    }
    // assert(div !== null);
    const checkbox = div.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]");
    // assert(checkbox !== null);
    const label = checkbox.parentElement;
    if (checkbox.checked) {
        label.classList.add("asanism-selected-radio");
    } else {
        label.classList.remove("asanism-selected-radio");
    }
}
```

---

Finally: It looks like your HTML has a `label` within a `label`. That's [invalid HTML](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-label-element):

> **`label`**
>
> ...
>
> Content model:
>
> Phrasing content, but with no descendant labelable elements unless it is the element's labeled control, and **no descendant `label` elements**.

*(my emphasis)*

Comment: We have more than one checkbox. How can we define which input is intended to change?

Comment: @HassanMonfared - Where is the event handler attached?

Comment: @HassanMonfared - I've gone ahead and added to the answer to explain how to handle it if the handler is on a `div` higher up in the document.